# Ensuring windows form is responsive

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote an application that takes a main folder and copies all the files that are in all sub folders of the main folder.  It works but when I copy a lot of files the form will be "not responding" for a while till it finishes.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
    private void buttonCopy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayList existingFiles = new ArrayList();
            string existingFileName = "";
            string thePath = folderSelect.Text;
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(thePath);
            FileInfo[] allFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (FileInfo file in allFiles)
            {
                string fullName = file.FullName;
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullName);
                bool fileExists;
                fileExists = File.Exists(folderSave.Text + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fileName);
                if (!fileExists)
                {
                    file.CopyTo(folderSave.Text + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    existingFileName += fileName + "\n";
                    existingFiles.Add(existingFileName);
                }

            }
            if (existingFiles.Count != 0)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(existingFiles.Count + " Files already exists!\n\n" + existingFileName);
            }
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Files copied successfully!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into `Threading`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `asynchnous` treatment

```
public class AsyncCopy
    {
        public delegate void CopyDelegate(string sourceFile, string destFile);

        public static void AsynFileCopy(string sourceFile, string destFile)
        {
            CopyDelegate del = new CopyDelegate(FileCopy);
            IAsyncResult result = del.BeginInvoke(sourceFile, destFile, CallBackAfterFileCopied, null);
        }

        public static void FileCopy(string sourceFile, string destFile)
        { 
            // Add here your code for copy
        }

        public static void CallBackAfterFileCopied(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            // Add here your callback logic
        }
    }
```